# Organizing / using reusable code libraries in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

My goal is to write some reusable (OO) code for communicating with an external API, but as I'm not well versed in this kind of stuff in PHP, I'm not sure what is the best way to organize and load my code.

Stuff like limiting the amount of knowledge the client code needs to have about the libraries classes and making sure there are no naming collisions has led me to experiments with namespacing and avoiding having to inlude all the library files have led to experiments with autoloading, but I have so many questions on the subject that in stead of a lengthy process of trial and error, I thought I'd see if I anyone here possessed some wisdom on the subject.

So I guess my main questions are:

- How to best encapsulate the library code, making it stand on it's own as much as possible.
- How to best load/call this library code from the client code.

... but feel free to expand on whatever you think should be considered. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to go about it is  simply to check how others do it Both Zend Framework and Symfony for instance will have a clear separation between these two. May not be a bad idea to borrow some concepts and make them your own.

I tend to simply put my library code and 'client code' in separate namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

What I can say that use OOP in php code to organize your code and reusable.

You can easily make a standalone class.

Comment: I'm using OOP. My question was supposed to be more about structuring and loading that OO code. I'll try to make the question clearer.